# $f(X \cap Y) \subset f(X) \cap f(Y) $

Tags: analysis

In class we had the following function which I intend to prove for my own peace of mind.

Let $M$ and $N$ be sets and $f: M \longrightarrow N$ a function:
\begin{align}f: P(M) &\longrightarrow P(N) \tag{P denotes Powerset} \\ X & \longmapsto \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in X \rbrace \end{align}
Let $X,Y \subset M$ then:
\begin{align} f(X \cap Y) \subset f(X) \cap f(Y) \end{align}
Note: In our book (Zorich Analysis) $\subset$ denotes a subset, not necessarily a real subset.

**Question: Is $f(X \cap Y) \subset f(X) \cap f(Y)$ a correct statement?**

So I know that I need to show $A \subset B \iff x \in A \longrightarrow x \in B$. I tried as follows:
\begin{align}f (X \cap Y) = \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in (X \cap Y)\rbrace \end{align}
I guess for the proof to be correct I should mention here that $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ because $x \in \emptyset$ would be a contradiction to start with.  I continued like this: 
\begin{align} x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in X \wedge x \in Y\rbrace \longrightarrow x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in X\rbrace \wedge x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in Y\rbrace \end{align}
I don't know if this step is correct or not, but it seemed like it to me, I could conclude from there that:
\begin{align}x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in X \wedge x \in Y\rbrace &\longrightarrow x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in X\rbrace \wedge x \in \lbrace f(x) \mid x \in Y\rbrace \\ & \longrightarrow x \in f(X) \wedge x \in  f(Y) \\ &\longrightarrow x \in ( f(X) \cap f(Y))
 \end{align}
Would this complete the proof? Or do I also need to show that $f(X) \cap f(Y) \not \subset f(X \cap Y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way of doing this is to show $f(X \cap Y) \subset f(X)$ and $f(X \cap Y) \subset f(Y)$, because a subset of $f(X) \cap f(Y)$ is the same as a subset of $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$. (More generally, a subset of $A \cap B$ is the same as a subset of $A$ and of $B$.)

But both follow from the more general statement that if $A \subset B$, then $f(A) \subset f(B)$. Indeed, any element of $f(A)$ is of the form $f(a)$ for some $a \in A$, whence $a \in B$, whence $f(a) \in f(B)$, i.e., any element of $f(A)$ is an element of $f(B)$. Now apply this statement to $A = X \cap Y$ and $B = X$ or $B= Y$.

Comment: Can I reason this through the following logical statement $(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (A \rightarrow C) \iff A \rightarrow (B \wedge C)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's very closely related. You can let $A$ be the proposition $x \in X$, $B$ the proposition $x \in Y$, etc. (where $X$ and $Y$ are adapted to the situation; what you wrote above is a good example of this).

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof.  The simplest way I see here is to use the definitions and predicate logic.

Using a slightly different notation, the definition of $\;f[A]\;$ is that
$$
b \in f[A] \;\equiv\; \langle \exists a : a \in A : f(a) = b \rangle
$$
for all $\;b\;$.  So the elements in the left hand side are those for which
\begin{align}
& b \in f[X \cap Y] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists a : a \in X \cap Y : f(a) = b \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
(*)\;\phantom{\equiv} & \langle \exists a : a \in X \land a \in Y : f(a) = b \rangle \\
\end{align}
And similarly for the right hand side, we have
\begin{align}
& b \in f[X] \cap f[Y] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& b \in f[X] \land b \in f[Y] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$, twice"} \\
(**)\;\phantom{\equiv} & \langle \exists a : a \in X : f(a) = b \rangle \land \langle \exists a : a \in Y : f(a) = b \rangle \\
\end{align}
Now predicate logic teaches us that the former $(*)$ implies the latter $(**)$ (since $\;\exists\;$ distributes over $\;\land\;$ in one direction), which proves $\;f[X \cap Y] \subseteq f[X] \cap f[Y]\;$ by the definition of $\;\subseteq\;$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this proof with me, I enjoy applying such definitions a lot and I will definitely include it in my summary for my learning review. It's very nice to see how much 'power' is within this particular notation :-) I will see how often I can apply this to other proofs. Thanks again.